# Inherited hook: create different singleton class for two different subclasses

Tags: ruby, singleton, anonymous-class

I've been messing around with singleton classes in Ruby and I came across some behavior I don't understand.

```
class A
    def self.inherited(subclass)
        class << subclass
            @@a = 5
            def a
                @@a
            end
            def a=(value)
                @@a = value
            end
        end
    end 
end

class B < A
end

class C < A 
end

B.a    # => 5
C.a    # => 5
B.a= 7
C.a    # => 7
```

Shouldn't ruby create a different singleton class for B and C? Why are B and C sharing the same anonymous class?

Answer (score 1):

They are not sharing the same singleton class.

```
B.singleton_class
# => #<Class:B>
C.singleton_class
# => #<Class:C>
```

But the singleton classes are both subclasses of the singleton class of `A`.

```
B.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [
  #<Class:B>,
  #<Class:A>,
  #<Class:Object>,
  #<Class:BasicObject>,
  Class,
  Module,
  Object,
  Kernel,
  BasicObject
]
C.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [
  #<Class:C>,
  #<Class:A>,
  #<Class:Object>,
  #<Class:BasicObject>,
  Class,
  Module,
  Object,
  Kernel,
  BasicObject
]
```

Comment: So what class does the class variable `@@a` belong to?

Comment: @griest To `A`. `A.class_variable_get(:@@a) # => 5`.

Comment: Why does `@@a` gets assigned to A as opposed to the singleton class?

Comment: @griest They are not opposing. It is because one is the singleton class of the other.